# calculating total weight of cart in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get my cart total weight in order to use it in my shipping calculator.

here is my code:

```
@foreach($item->attributes as $sss)
  {{number_format($item->quantity * $sss['value'], 0)}} KG
@endforeach
```

here is how it looks like:

[image: result1]

I need to get `92` as sample.

> PS: I really prefer if I can do it in backend and have something like
> `{{$total_weight}}` in front-end only.

how can I do that?

## UPDATE

[image: screen2]

Comment: Please show unfolded result of `{{ dd($item) }}`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin updated.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin why delete your answer!? it was working just fine :). any issue in it?

Comment: I've deleted it accidentally and restored in like 5 seconds. ) Please refresh the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try:**

```
$totalWeight = $items->sum(function ($item) {
    return $item->attributes->sum(function ($attribute) use($item) {
         $val = 0;
         $val += $item->quantity * $attribute['value'];
         return $val;
    });
});
```

Comment: it's kind of multi level my weight, please see my update. I shared dd

Comment: Call to a member function sum() on array

Comment: I think you forgot `*` times part, it supposed to be times to items quantity

Comment: @mafortis I have modified my answer :)

Comment: you put me in hard position :) @AlexeyMezenin answer works just fine too. confused :))

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin is a legend. I'm still a novice and learning every day.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`sum()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sum) method like this:

```
$items->sum(function($item) {
    return $item->quantity * $item->attributes->attr['value'];
});
```

Comment: sorry dude both of you answers working really confused who to accept :)  Thank you.

Comment: @mafortis you should accept the answer the code from which you'll be actually using in your app.